# Draw a polygon in python turtle centered

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I want to draw a polygon in the center of the screen, and i want the center of the polygon to be 0, 0. How do i do this? (There are many inputs and other stuff. I have pointed the direction at 45, that was an accident (but octagon is what i am imagining for tests)

```
import turtle

# THIS IS ALSO POSSIBLE WITH A FUNCTION AND ARGUMENTS, I WAS TOO BORED TO DO THAT

# initiate turtle, make a turtle
polygon_turtle = turtle.Turtle('turtle')

# inputs sides, length, edgecolor, fillcolor, show/hide artist, thickness of sides
sides = int(input('How many sides do you want on this regular polygon: '))
length = int(input('How long do you want each side to be: '))
edgecolor = input('What\'s the color for the sides of your polygon? ')
iffill = input('Do you want your polygon to be colored in? [Y/N]: ')
thickness = int(input('What do you want the width of the outline to be? '))
visibility = input('Do you want to see the artist that draws the polygon? [Y/N]: ')

# setup artist
polygon_turtle.pencolor(edgecolor)
polygon_turtle.pensize(thickness)
if iffill == 'Y':
    fillcolor = input('What do you want your fill color to be? ')
    polygon_turtle.fillcolor(fillcolor)
if visibility == 'N':
    polygon_turtle.hideturtle()

# center the polygon
polygon_turtle.penup()
polygon_turtle.goto(?????)
polygon_turtle.setheading(45)
polygon_turtle.pendown()

# draw polygon
polygon_turtle.begin_fill()
for i in range(sides):
    # use length as forward parameters, 360/sides as turn right parameters
    polygon_turtle.forward(length)
    polygon_turtle.right(360 / sides)
polygon_turtle.end_fill()

turtle.done()
```

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon):

> The circumradius R from the center of a regular polygon to one of the vertices is related to the side length s by R = s / (2 * sin(pi / n)).

That's how far you have to go in the beginning, if the turtle starts in the middle and you want to start drawing from one of the vertices. Translated into Python, using your variables:

```py
import math

R = length / (2 * math.sin(math.pi / sides))
```

Now you can draw the polygon like this (starting in the middle):

1. Go forward in any direction for a distance of `R`, without drawing.
2. Turn left (say) by `90 + 360 / (2 * sides)` degrees.
3. Start drawing.
4. Do `sides` times:

   - Go forward for a distance of `length`.
   - Turn left by `360 / sides` degrees.

Answer (score 0):

[Circles can be used to draw polygons](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle), with their optional 'steps' parameter.

if you want to draw the entire object in one go, it would be:

```
turtle .circle( radius,  steps = sides )
```

if you want your turtle to draw it out side-by-side, it would be:

```
for i in range( sides ):
    turtle .circle( radius,  extent = 360 /sides,  steps = sides )
    turtle .left( 360 /sides )
```

You could further divvy down each line-segment, if you really wanted to, by shrinking down that 'extents' value;  but it would require a nested loop to accomplish:

```
segments_per_side = 5
for i in range( sides ):
    for j in range( line_segments_per_side ):
        turtle .circle( radius,  extent = 360 /sides /segments_per_side,  steps = sides )
    turtle .left( 360 /sides )
```

Comment: Too tired to test that right now, but you might have to multiply `segments_per_side` by j then add 1, so it starts from 1-index...  so it would be something like `extent = 360 /sides /segments_per_side *(j +1)`  You get the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of [Arne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13014172/arne) , you just need to use

```
polygon_turtle.goto(x coordinate that you want, y coordinate that you want)
```

Here you said that "i want the center of the polygon to be 0"
so use something like this as the origin is at the center of the screen:

```
polygon_turtle.goto(0, 0)
```

and rest is the follow up of [Arne's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13014172/arne) answer with a little change with the turtle moving to the right not left(otherwise it will be not centered).
Hence the complete code for centering the polygon will be:

```
# center the polygon
polygon_turtle.goto(0,0)
R = length / (2 * math.sin(math.pi / sides))
polygon_turtle.forward(R)
polygon_turtle.right(90+(360 / (2 * sides)))
```

and don't forget to import math :), no other change is there anywhere..